# Android 6.0 : How many times "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale" get called?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I recently started development on android 6.0 -- runtime permission request.

I wanted to know how many times `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` method is get called.

**Here is my code:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LaunchActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){

            dbOperation();

            if (NetworkUtil.isServiceReachable(this)){
                checkAppVersion();
            } else {
                startApplication();
            }

        } else {

            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(LaunchActivity.this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to Storage/Media for storing your Records.",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LaunchActivity.this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                        PermissionConstants.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
                            }
                        });
                return;

            }
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LaunchActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},PermissionConstants.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }

    }
```

**And in callback method I do:**

```
  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
       // super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode){

            case PermissionConstants.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION:{
                if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                    dbOperation();
                    // Permission is granted Read and Write external storage.
                    if (NetworkUtil.isServiceReachable(this)){
                        checkAppVersion();
                    } else {
                        startApplication();
                    }

                }else {

                    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(LaunchActivity.this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to Storage/Media for storing your Records.",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LaunchActivity.this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                                PermissionConstants.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
                                    }
                                });
                        return;
                    }else {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LaunchActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},PermissionConstants.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);

                    }
                    //break;
                }
            }
            break;
default:super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

In this scenario. when user denies permission without selecting don.t ask again, android shows request permission dialog 2 times and then it goes in infinite loop.

1. I wanted to know what happens if user denies request multiple times without selecting `don't ask again` check box ?
2. What happens if user selects `don't ask again` check box and denies the request ?

Is `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` method get called in this scenario ?

If **Yes**, how many times?

If **No** why isn't ?

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: it will call only once.

Answer (score 0):

1. If user denies request multiple times without selecting don't ask again checkbox, you will always get true for shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(). So its developer's decision to keep annoying user with Rationale dialog and permission request dialog loop or to consider it as Denied when showing permission request dialog second time after showing Rationale dialog.
2. If user select Don't ask again check box and denies the request, you will get false for shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() i.e. user denied the permission.

So suggested flow should be:-

1. On application start checkselfpermission granted or not. If granted start main activity.
2. If not granted, show permission request dialog.
3. In onRequestPermissionsResult callback, check the permission status granted or denied, if granted start main activity.
4. If denied then check shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(), if yes then show Permission Rationale dialog and then again Permission request dialog.
5. Again in onRequestPermissionsResult callback, check the permission status granted or denied, if granted start main activity.
6. If denied, repeat step 4.
7. If user has selected Never Ask Again, then you will get shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() false and that means user do not wish to allow for permission and then you can decide whether the permission is important without which application could not function then show appropriate alert to user and stop the application or else start application with limited functionality.
8. If user has not selected Never Ask Again but denied, then you will get shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() true and there you have to decide whether to show the Rationale dialog again or not.
9. Here you have a choice, if permission is such that without that application could not function then either show appropriate alert message to user and stop the application or show Rationale with more detail to explain user to allow the permission.
10. If permission is such that without that application can function with limited functionality then either show main activity or again show rationale dialog.
11. So thing is unless user selects **Never ask again** while Denying, shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() will always return true and its developer decision whether to keep showing Rationale dialog and permission dialog again n again or not.